# error in printing data using template module

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I have little problem with printing data like this, I have written script like this

```
[% FOREACH comp IN company %]
[% comp.name %] 
[% comp.location%]
employeedata:
[% FOREACH employee IN comp.domain.java.employee %]

[% FOREACH experiance IN employee.experiance %]

[% FOREACH obj IN ObjectDefinition%]

[% FOREACH beha IN obj.experiance %]

[% IF beha.years == experiance.years %] 

 [% beha.Name %],
  [% LAST %]
 [% END %]
   [% END %]
 [% END %]
 [% END %]
[% END %]
  [% END %]
```

from above script comparing "years" value in two keys in a hash and if both are same print the employee name. Its working and it printing like this as show below.

if three names is there it printing like this.

```
  clar, larson, per,
```

if two names is there it printing like this.

```
clar, larson,
```

but I need to print like this 
if three names is there

```
clar, larson or per.
```

if two names is there like this

```
clar, larson.
```

if only one name is there like this

```
clar.
```

I have maximum number of names is three only. I need to print like this help me how to print like this. if any mistakes is there excuse me please.

I tried like this also

```
 [% FOREACH employee IN comp.domain.java.employee %]

[% FOREACH experience IN employee.experience %]

[% FOREACH obj IN ObjectDefinition%]

[% FOREACH beha IN obj.experience %]

 [% IF beha.years == experience.years %]

 [% IF employee.experience.size == 1 %]
 [% beha.Name %].


 [% ELSIF employee.experience.size == 2 %]
     [% beha.Name %],[% beha.Name %].


[% ELSIF employee.experience.size == 3 %] 
 [% beha.Name %],[% beha.Name %]or[% beha.Name %].
 [% END %]
  [% END %]
  [% END %]
  [% END %]
  [% END %]
  [% END %]
```

but it printing when we have one name. if we have two names it printing like this

```
clar,clar.
larson,larson.
```

if we have three names it printing like this

```
clar,clar or clar.
larson,larson or larson.
per,per or per.
```

what is wrong with my script I cant solve this problem can any body help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second attempt is definitely closer to what you're going to need. But the order of the loops doesn't look right. `beha.Name` is only ever going to have the value of the current record.

I think you want something like this:

```
[%  SET staff = []; # empty list 
    FOREACH beha IN obj.experience;
        staff.push(beha) IF beha.years == experience.years;
    END; %]
[%  IF staff.size == 1;
        staff.0.Name;
    ELSIF staff.size == 2;
        "$staff.0.Name, $staff.1.Name";
    ELSIF staff.size >= 3;
        "$staff.0.Name, $staff.1.Name or $staff.2.Name";
    END %]
```

The IF-ELSIF loop is not very pretty, but there's no obvious staff.join() construction that's going to do what you need with that mix of commas and text separators and a limit of 3 elements.

**UPDATE**

As requested, an example using .join:

If you had an arbitrary length list of names, you might want to present them as *name, name, [name, ...] or name*:

```
ELSIF staff.size >= 3;
    SET lastname = staff.pop; #remove last person from list
    staff.join(', '); " or $lastname";
END;
```

But as I said previously, with a maximum of 3 names, this is overkill.

Comment: thanks for you suggestion, Can you provide one example for using staff.join().

Comment: See updated answer - I've added an example. Just as an aside, the official documentation for TT is very good. Have a look at the entry in the manual titled "VMethods".

Comment: Thank you very much for providing example.